# MySQL If condition in where clause query

Tags: mysql

I have a table as below  and a USR table which shows is a user is admin or a regular user. In this case USR_ID: 1 is as admin

```
EMP_ID     Terminated    EMP_Name      EMP_Loc
  1         0            John         Caster
  2         1            Sally        Jules
  3         0            Steven        James
```

This is a EMP db table and EMP#2 is terminated and when a regular user queries the DB, the terminated Employee's should not be shown and while an admin queries the DB, i would like to show all the employee's including the terminated ones.

Here is my query

```
 select * from EMP join USR on USR.ID = EMP.EMP_ID
 where (IF USR.ID = '1',terminated='1',terminated in ('0','1'))
```

but this query only show non-terminated users always even for admin user

Comment: Can you shou USR table schema?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use OR in your where condition, something like

```
select * from EMP join USR on USR.ID = EMP.EMP_ID
where (USR.ID = '1' and terminated='1') or (USR.ID <> '1' and terminated in ('0','1'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   EMP 
       INNER JOIN USR ON USR.ID = EMP.EMP_ID
WHERE
       (USR.ID = '1' AND Terminaded = '1') OR (USR.ID <> '1')
```

Answer (score 0):

As your requirement, you can try this:

```
select * 
from EMP join USR on USR.ID = EMP.EMP_ID
where (USR.ID <> '1' and Terminated = '1') or (Terminated in ('0', '1'))
```

if `Terminated` only have two value '0' or '1', you can remove `or` clause:

```
select * 
from EMP join USR on USR.ID = EMP.EMP_ID
where (USR.ID <> '1' and Terminated = '1')
```